# Unable to connect to usb device (Emotiv neuroheadset) in linux

Tags: c, linux, usb, driver, hardware

I have emotiv headset which I'm trying to use with its opensource driver. The device is listed in usbls, but no communication with device is possible. Running strace on executable of drivers leads me to suspicion that some libraries may be missing, but I cannot google out which ones.

I'm using the following example program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include "emokit/emokit.h"

int quit;
void cleanup(int i){
        fprintf(stdout,"Shutting down\n");
        quit=1; 
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        struct emokit_device* d;
        signal(SIGINT, cleanup); //trap cntrl c


        quit=0;

        d = emokit_create();
        int count=emokit_get_count(d, EMOKIT_VID, EMOKIT_PID);
        printf("Current epoc devices connected: %d\n", count );
        int r = emokit_open(d, EMOKIT_VID, EMOKIT_PID, 1);
        if(r != 0)
        {
                emokit_close(d);
                emokit_delete(d);
                d = emokit_create();
                r = emokit_open(d, EMOKIT_VID, EMOKIT_PID, 0);
                if (r!=0) {
                        printf("CANNOT CONNECT: %d\n", r);
                        return 1;
                }
        }
        printf("Connected to headset.\n");

        if (emokit_read_data(d)<=0) {
                printf("Error reading from headset\n");
                emokit_close(d);
                emokit_delete(d);
                return 1;
        }

        struct emokit_frame c;
        while (!quit) {
                if(emokit_read_data(d) > 0) {
                        c = emokit_get_next_frame(d);
                        fprintf(stdout,"\033[H\033[2JPress CTRL+C to exit\n\nContact quality:\nF3  %4d\nFC6 %4d\nP7  %4d\nT8  %4d\nF7  %4d\nF8  %4d\nT7  %4d\nP8  %4d\nAF4 %4d\nF4  %4d\nAF3 %4d\nO2  %4d\nO1  %4d\nFC5 %4d",c.cq.F3, c.cq.FC6, c.cq.P7, c.cq.T8,c.cq.F7, c.cq.F8, c.cq.T7, c.cq.P8, c.cq.AF4, c.cq.F4, c.cq.AF3, c.cq.O2, c.cq.O1, c.cq.FC5);
                        fflush(stdout);
                } 
        }
        emokit_close(d);
        emokit_delete(d);
        return 0;
}
```

trying to run in results in

```
./contact 
Current epoc devices connected: 0
CANNOT CONNECT: -3
```

the usb dongle however is correctly identified by my Ubuntu mint 14.04 and is listed in 
lsusb as

```
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 1234:ed02 Brain Actuated Technologies Emotiv EPOC Developer Headset Wireless Dongle
```

strace results below lead me to idea that something must be missing from my system (judging by the number of "No such file or directory" lines in strace)

```
sudo strace ./contact
[sudo] password for user: 
execve("./contact", ["./contact"], [/* 17 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0xe16000
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f7ebe8bc000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/lib/tls/x86_64/libmcrypt.so.4", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/local/lib/tls/x86_64", 0x7fffd58225d0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/lib/tls/libmcrypt.so.4", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/local/lib/tls", 0x7fffd58225d0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/lib/x86_64/libmcrypt.so.4", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/local/lib/x86_64", 0x7fffd58225d0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/lib/libmcrypt.so.4", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/local/lib", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=155101, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 155101, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f7ebe896000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/libmcrypt.so.4", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0@S\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=187824, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2306080, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f7ebe468000
mprotect(0x7f7ebe492000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f7ebe692000, 16384, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x2a000) = 0x7f7ebe692000
mmap(0x7f7ebe696000, 20512, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f7ebe696000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/usr/local/lib/libhidapi-hidraw.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhidapi-hidraw.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\0\27\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=14648, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2109856, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f7ebe264000
mprotect(0x7f7ebe267000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f7ebe466000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x2000) = 0x7f7ebe466000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/usr/local/lib/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\320\37\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1845024, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f7ebe895000
mmap(NULL, 3953344, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f7ebde9e000
mprotect(0x7f7ebe059000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f7ebe259000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1bb000) = 0x7f7ebe259000
mmap(0x7f7ebe25f000, 17088, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f7ebe25f000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/usr/local/lib/libudev.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\0200\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=67600, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2164816, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f7ebdc8d000
mprotect(0x7f7ebdc9d000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f7ebde9c000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0xf000) = 0x7f7ebde9c000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/usr/local/lib/libcgmanager.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcgmanager.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\0206\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=108480, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2203688, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f7ebda72000
mprotect(0x7f7ebda8b000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f7ebdc8a000, 12288, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x18000) = 0x7f7ebdc8a000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/usr/local/lib/libnih.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnih.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0`G\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=96280, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f7ebe894000
mmap(NULL, 2191776, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f7ebd85a000
mprotect(0x7f7ebd871000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f7ebda70000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x16000) = 0x7f7ebda70000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/usr/local/lib/libnih-dbus.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnih-dbus.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\340,\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=38920, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2134040, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f7ebd650000
mprotect(0x7f7ebd658000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f7ebd858000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x8000) = 0x7f7ebd858000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/usr/local/lib/libdbus-1.so.3", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0@h\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=281552, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2377408, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f7ebd40b000
mprotect(0x7f7ebd44f000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f7ebd64e000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x43000) = 0x7f7ebd64e000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/usr/local/lib/librt.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0P#\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=31792, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f7ebe893000
mmap(NULL, 2129016, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f7ebd203000
mprotect(0x7f7ebd20a000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f7ebd409000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x6000) = 0x7f7ebd409000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/usr/local/lib/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0po\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=141574, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2217264, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f7ebcfe5000
mprotect(0x7f7ebcffe000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f7ebd1fd000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x18000) = 0x7f7ebd1fd000
mmap(0x7f7ebd1ff000, 13616, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f7ebd1ff000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f7ebe892000
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f7ebe890000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f7ebe890740) = 0
mprotect(0x7f7ebe259000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f7ebd1fd000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f7ebd409000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f7ebd64e000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f7ebda70000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f7ebd858000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f7ebdc8a000, 8192, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f7ebde9c000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f7ebe466000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f7ebe692000, 8192, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x603000, 4096, PROT_READ)     = 0
mprotect(0x7f7ebe8be000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7f7ebe896000, 155101)          = 0
set_tid_address(0x7f7ebe890a10)         = 5344
set_robust_list(0x7f7ebe890a20, 24)     = 0
futex(0x7fffd5822e10, FUTEX_WAIT_BITSET_PRIVATE|FUTEX_CLOCK_REALTIME, 1, NULL, 7f7ebe890740) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
rt_sigaction(SIGRTMIN, {0x7f7ebcfeb9f0, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_SIGINFO, 0x7f7ebcff5340}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_1, {0x7f7ebcfeba80, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, 0x7f7ebcff5340}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [RTMIN RT_1], NULL, 8) = 0
getrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, {rlim_cur=8192*1024, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {0x4015ad, [INT], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7f7ebded4c30}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0xe16000
brk(0xe37000)                           = 0xe37000
uname({sys="Linux", node="stribog", ...}) = 0
uname({sys="Linux", node="stribog", ...}) = 0
open("/etc/udev/udev.conf", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=148, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f7ebe8bb000
read(3, "# see udev(7) for details\n#\n# ud"..., 4096) = 148
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0x7f7ebe8bb000, 4096)            = 0
stat("/sys/subsystem", 0x7fffd5822be0)  = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/bus", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
getdents(3, /* 29 entries */, 32768)    = 800
getdents(3, /* 0 entries */, 32768)     = 0
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/class", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
getdents(3, /* 54 entries */, 32768)    = 1600
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/class/hidraw", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
getdents(4, /* 2 entries */, 32768)     = 48
getdents(4, /* 0 entries */, 32768)     = 0
close(4)                                = 0
getdents(3, /* 0 entries */, 32768)     = 0
close(3)                                = 0
fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0600, st_rdev=makedev(136, 4), ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f7ebe8bb000
write(1, "Current epoc devices connected: "..., 34Current epoc devices connected: 0
) = 34
uname({sys="Linux", node="stribog", ...}) = 0
open("/etc/udev/udev.conf", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=148, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f7ebe8ba000
read(3, "# see udev(7) for details\n#\n# ud"..., 4096) = 148
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0x7f7ebe8ba000, 4096)            = 0
stat("/sys/subsystem", 0x7fffd5822bd0)  = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/bus", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
getdents(3, /* 29 entries */, 32768)    = 800
getdents(3, /* 0 entries */, 32768)     = 0
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/class", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
getdents(3, /* 54 entries */, 32768)    = 1600
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/class/hidraw", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
getdents(4, /* 2 entries */, 32768)     = 48
getdents(4, /* 0 entries */, 32768)     = 0
close(4)                                = 0
getdents(3, /* 0 entries */, 32768)     = 0
close(3)                                = 0
uname({sys="Linux", node="stribog", ...}) = 0
uname({sys="Linux", node="stribog", ...}) = 0
open("/etc/udev/udev.conf", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=148, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f7ebe8ba000
read(3, "# see udev(7) for details\n#\n# ud"..., 4096) = 148
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0x7f7ebe8ba000, 4096)            = 0
stat("/sys/subsystem", 0x7fffd5822bd0)  = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/bus", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
getdents(3, /* 29 entries */, 32768)    = 800
getdents(3, /* 0 entries */, 32768)     = 0
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/class", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
getdents(3, /* 54 entries */, 32768)    = 1600
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/class/hidraw", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
getdents(4, /* 2 entries */, 32768)     = 48
getdents(4, /* 0 entries */, 32768)     = 0
close(4)                                = 0
getdents(3, /* 0 entries */, 32768)     = 0
close(3)                                = 0
write(1, "CANNOT CONNECT: -3\n", 19CANNOT CONNECT: -3
)    = 19
exit_group(1)                           = ?
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that there are any libraries missing. Your program wouldn't even run if any of library wasn't available. I'd rather check if EMOKIT_VID and EMOKIT_PID have proper values, because as you said - linux recognizes this device, but only application cannot connect to this device.

Comment: Use "lsusb -v" and take a look at idVendor and idProduct - probably it will be 1234 and ed02. Then check if values of EMOKIT_VID and EMOKIT_PID are the same.